Sampling random matrices where all rows and all columns have Euclidean norm 1
I'd like to samples some matrices where $L_2$ norms of rows and columns are $1$. This is similar to "doubly stochastic matrices" where $L_1$ norms are $1$. Overview here.
Can anyone suggest an algorithm to obtain such matrices?
Motivation: I'm debugging some coordinate descent algorithms for linear least squares (which work on columns of the data matrix), and I'd like to reuse guarantees/predictions from Kaczmarz-type algorithm (which work on rows of the data matrix).

So, you are essentially looking for matrices $A$ such that the diagonals of $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ are all $1$’s, correct?

@mdhack yes, that's a good way of putting it

I think rotation matrices are then definitely a group of examples then ?

@dezdichado I think OP wants rectangular matrices not square matrices, since a “data matrix” is usually rectangular.

@dezdichado good point, that's one way. Would be interesting to get this for rectangular matrices too (unclear if it's feasible)

i suppose one can pad with zeros but that's probably not useful. Also, can't you just take a regular doubly stochastic matrix with non-negative entries and then take entrywise square root ? I feel like I am misunderstanding something here.

Okay unless I am misunderstanding something such a matrix can only exist as a square matrix for otherwise, you have:
$$n=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ma^2_{ij}=m.$$
For square matrices, a good family of example is given by Orthogonal matrices and they should give you a plenty of random enough examples though.
EDIT:
For fun and for $n=3,$ following seems to give one way of parametrizing by taking the entrywise square root of :
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 -m^2-x^2 & m^2+x^2-c^2 & c^2\\ 
x^2 & 1-z^2-x^2 & z^2\\
m^2 & n^2 & p^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
where you take $c^2+z^2=m^2+n^2=1-p^2$ whatever way you want and then choose $x$ to satisfy $1-z^2-x^2\geq 0, 1-m^2-x^2\geq 0$ and $m^2+x^2-c^2\geq 0,$ which I believe is equivalent to:
$$\sqrt{\max\{0, c^2-m^2\}}\leq x \leq \sqrt{\min\{1-z^2, 1-m^2\}}.$$
Of course, there is nothing special about "fixing" the third row and column which this choice can be permuted.
It seems to me that up to entrywise absolute value, the space of all such matrices is essentially the same as the space of doubly stochastic matrices, which apparently is a $(n-1)^2$ dimensional affine space and can be generated by taking a convex combination of an arbitrary number of $n$-dimensional permutation matrices.

"Random" only in an informal way - most reasonable distributions over the matrices in the question should have probability $0$ of being orthogonal.

To complete the answer: One can uniformly sample from the orthogonal group by sampling $n$ independent Gaussian vectors and applying Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation.

(+1) In case OP is interested in the more general case when either each row or each column (but not both) of a rectangular matrix have unit $L_2$ norm, then this answer provides a way of sampling these kinds of matrices.

Agreed. If OP wants to be able to sample uniformly from the space of such matrices, I think the question needs to be updated and someone else can give an answer.
